# php string end identify

Tags: php

If I have a php string called $a.  It can either end in a k or not end with a k.

If it ends with a k, then I want to do nothing, but if it does not end with a k then I want to add the string $b to the end.  How can I recognise what the string $a ends with to do this?

```
$a=asdk ----> do nothing
$a=asdtt ---->add string $b(=rrk say) to make it $a=asdttrrk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access a specific character using `$a[i]`, so the last character would be `$a[strlen($a) - 1]`.

Answer (score 6):

Use this method:

```
if ($a[strlen($a) -1] !== 'k') $a .= $b;
```

alternative

```
if (substr($a, -1) !== 'k') $a .= $b;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$last_char = $a[count($a) - 1];

if ($last_char == 'k') {
     //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also [substr_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php):

```
// test 1
$a = "asdfasdf";
$b = "foo";
$a .= (substr_compare($a, 'k', -strlen('k'), strlen('k')) === 0) ? "" : $b;
echo $a; // asdfasdffoo

echo "\n\n";

// test 2
$a = "asdfasdkkkk";
$b = "foo";
$a .= (substr_compare($a, 'k', -strlen('k'), strlen('k')) === 0) ? "" : $b;
echo $a; // asdfasdkkkk
```

[**Try it out here.**](http://www.ideone.com/jGnlu)

Comment: ...and now when I look at it, it seems *completely* ridiculous!

Answer (score 0):

```
function isLast($str) {
    return $str[strlen($str)-1];
}

$string = 'abcdefghijk';

if(isLast($string) == 'k') {
    echo 'true';
}
else {
    echo 'false';
}
```

Yet another version (if you prefer using custom functions)